# add (AdMob) size could be fill_parent insted wrap_content?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, admob, banner

my add makes some view scale problems . i solved it by making android:layout_width fill_parent insted wrap_content .

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/ad"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="axxxxxx"
                ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

any issues with that i should be aware of or its ok ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Fill_parent` on the width is fine, as long as you understand what it means. Basically, the ad will be 320x50 but the view will span the entire width, so you can't place any other views in that area.

If you're going with full width, you may consider the `SMART_BANNER` ad size as well, which will fill that entire space with an ad.